# how to assign json.stringify() to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string, integer

Here in this code, i want to achieve to calculate the sum of particular data that i took from excel file by this line :

```js
 " sumofKoli += JSON.stringify(row.values[4]);".
```

My problem is that even this line of code :

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(row.values[3])+" Sold number of :"+ JSON.stringify(row.values[4]));
```

Gives what i want like "47" which i exactly want as an integer, when i try to sum all the data i am having a result which is like "94559129995555.5.2556149.9". It adds it as a string value, i want it to sum as integer. Can you help me ?

Here is the full code :

```js
Reader.prototype.readExcel = function(chartType,callback){


  // read from a file
  var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  var sumofKoli=0;
  var sumPrice =0;
  workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
      .then(function(err,results) {
          var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sayfa1');
          worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
            console.log("----------");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row.values[3])+" Sold number of :"+ JSON.stringify(row.values[4]));
            console.log("----------");
            sumofKoli += JSON.stringify(row.values[4]);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row.values[3])+" Sold in price of  :"+ JSON.stringify(row.values[5]));
            sumPrice += JSON.stringify(row.values[5]);
            console.log("----------");

          });
          results = { sumofKoli : sumofKoli, sumTutar : sumPrice};
          if (err){callback(err,null);}

          callback(null,results);
      });
```

Comment: You are trying to add variable of type `string` with variable of type `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the string to Number

`sumofKoli += parseInt(JSON.stringify(row.values[4]))`;

Comment: he specifically said he wants an Integer though

Comment: thank you all for your answers but it returns NaN when i try :

  sumPrice += parseFloat(JSON.stringify(row.values[5]));

  sumPrice += parseFloat(JSON.stringify(row.values[5]));

both solutions return "NaN" value.

Comment: can you give us the data within the row object

Comment: Okay, NaN was the result of blocks. Now, i am able to get the sum of the row data. thank you so much !

Comment: why would one stringify a number just to immediately parse it back to a Number? how about: `sumofKoli += Math.floor(row.values[4])`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your json'd values to integers with the `parseInt` (or `parseFloat` if you have decimals) functions when trying to sum them.

As your values are currently considered strings, it currently concatenate them instead of adding them.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is only integer, then use `parseInt` instead of `JSON.stringify` while adding. In case you have float values too, use `parseFloat`. Syntax is simple:

`sumofKoli += parseInt(row.values[index])`

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking to sum integers, so similar to Vladu Ionut's answer it should be:

`sumofKoli += parseInt(JSON.stringify(row.values[4]));`

But, why are you stringigying a JSON and then parsing it? Why not use the value directly?

`sumofKoli += parseInt(row.values[4]);`

It seems odd to stringify something just to cast it afterwards.